# Что нужно знать для начала программирования на React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Мой стаж уже больше 5 лет, делаю сайты на заказ, делаю всё в стоке html, css, js, php и sql все эти языки я знаю если не на 5 то на крепкую 4 точно. Хочу создать мобильное приложение на React Native, проблема в том что React агромен, и вопрос нужно ли изучить весь React или будет достаточно изучить React Native по одному из многочисленных курсов, скажем что нужно знать для того чтобы запустить первый экран с надписью "Hello World"

Answer (score 1):

В интернете есть классический мем на тему "рисуем сову в два шага: 1) рисуем два овала 2) рисуем оставшуюся часть - собственно, сову".

Так и с реактом.

Ключевая идея реакта очень проста:

вместо разрозненных элементов управления, состояние которых можно менять как угодно, есть некий связанный "каркас" или "структура", когда у *набора* элементов управления есть состояние, и изменение в каком то одном элементе управления *может* вызвать поток событий, которые поменяют состояние других элементов управления. И всё это общее состояние отображается в state реакта.

Оборотной стороной является то, что страница, "набитая" элементами управления, взаимно однозначно отображается на state - то есть, достаточно знать state, чтобы, например, воспроизвести баг, который случился у пользователя.

Эта простая идея соответствует первому элементу мема: "рисуем два овала"

А потом начинается самый хардкор. Дальше эта идея обрастает подробностями, практиками использования и boilerplate - кодом, который надо писать в том или другом случае.

Именно из за этого хардкора реакт и кажется таким огромным.

Но базовый курс по реакту (обычному, для WEB) помещается примерно в два десятка видеоуроков, каждый из которых содержит 15-20 мин видео, и набор упражнений - говорю это по воспоминаниям об одном курсе, который прослушал.

В принципе, это немного, и можно послушать даже "для расширения кругозора".

React Native - это распространение той же самой идеи на нативные контролы для конкретной OS. Которые теперь будут связаны уже привычным react-синтаксисом и привычным javascript.

И вот это всё, как мне кажется, соответствует второму пункту мема: "рисуем сову целиком".

Для helloworlda достаточно послушать начало курса по обычному реакту, я думаю, это примерно 10% от всего курса.

Но есть проблема: обычно после HelloWorld для реакта Вы по прежнему не понимаете сценариев применения, в которых react даёт существенное преимущество